# pyinstaller: Reduce python executable final size with heavy library (Mediapipe)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, mediapipe, tflite

I'm developing a small app that uses Mediapipe to load a .tflite model to extract image embeddings and use cosine similarity to get the similar ones.

Everything is working, but I want to share it with a small community so they could just open it and use.

The problem is that the final image is with almost 100MB, not totally overwhelming, but yet too big.

I looked on my requirements and all the libraries install like 30MB, and when I install Mediapipe it install like 300MB of dependencies.

Any tips on how I could shrink it final size? Maybe some alternative library to Mediapipe.

The way I'm using it is this:

```
import mediapipe as mp
from pathlib import Path

BaseOptions = mp.tasks.BaseOptions
ImageEmbedder = mp.tasks.vision.ImageEmbedder
ImageEmbedderOptions = mp.tasks.vision.ImageEmbedderOptions
VisionRunningMode = mp.tasks.vision.RunningMode

model_path = Path(r"assets\models\1.tflite")

class Embedder():
    
    def __init__(self, model_path=model_path):
        model_path = Path(model_path)
        options = ImageEmbedderOptions(
            base_options=BaseOptions(model_asset_path=model_path),
            quantize=False,
            running_mode=VisionRunningMode.IMAGE)

        self.embedder = ImageEmbedder.create_from_options(options)
    
    def create_embed_from_np(self, numpy_image):
        return self.embedder.embed(mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=numpy_image)).embeddings[0]
    
    def create_embed_from_path(self, image_path):
        return self.embedder.embed(mp.Image.create_from_file(image_path.as_posix())).embeddings[0]
    
    def cosine_similarity(self, embed_1, embed_2):
        return ImageEmbedder.cosine_similarity(embed_1, embed_2)
```

Comment: which library/tool do you use to turn your python code into an executable?

Comment: I'm using this: `pyinstaller --onefile app/main.py`